# iOS - show consistent alert at the top of the UI when backgrounding the app (like personal hotspot does)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating an alarm clock app that requires some user action within the app in order to turn the alarm off. Below is a picture of what another app, Sleep Cycle, does when you turn an alarm on and press the home screen (i.e. background the app).

[Here is an image link](http://s28.postimg.org/vtkqesh19/IMG_3023_1.png) (I can't post an image yet, no rep despite my many attempts to answer people's questions today) for the effect I want to re-create.

Those that have used iPhone's Personal Hotspot and connected a device will notice that it is the same effect, where a notification appears at the top of the UI - pushing everything down by around 20-40 points. This is highly desirable to an alarm clock app as it encourages the user to keep the app in the foreground so that the app can easily be entered when waking up (instead of relying on the 30 second sound window allowed by local notifications)

Does anyone have any ideas on how to implement this functionality. I assume that it must go somewhere in the:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

tag within the AppDelegate, but I'm not sure what exactly I need to be reading up on. So if anyone has a link to some relevant Developer Docs that would also be extremely helpful.

Many thanks for your help,
Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a handful of built in 'background modes' that change the status bar's appearance depending on what functionality an app provides whilst it's in the background. The one you've identified (a red status bar) is triggered when an app records audio whilst in the background. I presume Sleep Cycle must be acting as though it records audio just for this purpose. Other background modes include VoIP (which I think uses a blue status bar). Check out [Apple's documentation on supporting these various background modes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24)

In your case, you'd want to add `audio` to the `UIBackgroundModes` property in your `Info.plist` file.

But note that it wouldn't be unreasonable for Apple to reject an app during review if it pretends to perform one of these background tasks but doesn't. For example, there have been apps in the past that tried playing a silent audio clip continuously in order to stay awake in the background - needless to say Apple got wise to this and the app in question had to change its behaviour.

Comment: That's interesting that Sleep Cycle is acting as though it is recording audio, since that doesn't appear to be a part of any of the functionality within the app. The app only tracks data from the accelerometer as far as I am aware, it uses this to analyse your sleeping patterns throughout the night. Do you think the red status bar could could also indicate this?

Comment: Yep, it's definitely unexpected. I've just opened up Sleep Cycle's `Info.plist` using iExplorer - I can confirm that it has the `audio` `UIBackgroundMode` set in there.

Comment: Ok thanks, I didn't know that iExplorer allows you to look at the Info.plist file that's really useful

Comment: Sleep cycle uses the microphone to detect movements while the user sleeps